# FreeBSD keyboard input is messed up

Tags: freebsd, keyboard

I have been using FreeBSD for over a week now with few problems. I set up an rc.d script to start an X server and when I boot my computer the X server crashes, sends me to vt01 and messes up my keyboard input so I can't type and therefore can't log in. For example k becomes % and alt becomes 8.

What could be happening, and how can I fix it without being able to log in?

The keyboard can type fine in the loader prompt.

Comment: What does your script do? Usually you don't need to write any rc scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You do not write whether X is usable before it crashes? Have you added yourself to the video group? Today it is better to let X autodetect settings but depending on your graphics card you might need to load additional drivers before starting X. Are you able to log in as a regular user and start X using `startx`? To diagnose what actually happens you can look at `/var/log/Xorg.log`. This will still be available after a reboot.

If your problem is that you always boot directly into X and crash then you can boot into single user mode. When booting press a key to get to the boot prompt. At the `boot:` prompt enter `boot -s`. You can then mount your filesystem with `/sbin/mount -ruw /` and edit your config to not start X (`vi` is your friend!). Then make sure you can start X manually in multi user with `startx` before attempting to start it at boot.

If you have SSH setup you could remote in and see what happens.

If you're lucky the easiest solution might be to change the VT console. Try with both `ALT-F3` and `CTRL-ALT-F3`. Which might work depends on the state of X and how your TTYs are mappend. The default in FreeBSD is to have X on `ALT-F9`.

Finally you write that you setup an rc.d script to start X. This sounds wrong to me. If you are using full desktop environments such as Gnome and KDE they already have a rc.d script so you only need to set `yes` in `rc.conf`. That would be `gnome_enable="YES"` or `kdm4_enable="YES"`

If you are using Xfce or mate then they come without a login manager. In that case you would typically login from the VT and then start x (maybe even automatically from a login script).

But if you want to automatically log into Xfce/Mate (actually log automatically into FreeBSD) then you would set the user up using `/etc/gettytab`. I am guessing you are not doing that.

If you want a graphical login then use a login manager. Gnome and KDE has GDM and KDM but they can be used by themselves as well. I usually use [slim](https://www.freshports.org/x11/slim/). You then assing the login manager to the VT you are using in `/etc/ttys` like so:

```
ttyv8  "/usr/local/bin/slim -nodaemon"  xterm  on secure
```

This will allow you to login with a graphical interface. It will then start your X environment based on your `.xinitrc`.

Getting X to run on FreeBSD requires very few steps and I would really recommend following [Chapter 5. The X Window System](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/x11.html) rather than rolling your own `rc.d` script.

Comment: "When booting press a key to get to the boot prompt. At the boot: prompt enter boot -s. You can then mount your filesystem with /sbin/mount -ruw / and edit your config to not start X (vi is your friend!). Then make sure you can start X manually in multi user with startx before attempting to start it at boot." Thank you, this solved it for me, and I found the root cause - a broken login manager. Also, "vi is your friend" Tell that to a die-hard emacs or nano fan :~)